# Substituting local resources by detecting URL scheme

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, http

I have built a class that intercepts `UIWebView` resource loading by subclassing `NSURLCache` and overriding `cachedResponseForRequest:`, similar to [this](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/09/substituting-local-data-for-remote.html) example.  Basically, if the requested resource is of type .css, I look for it in a local caches directory and if found, I load the local version.

The problem is that I now want to be able to specify which css files to look for in local cache, by providing a specific scheme that my app knows about. But when I change the scheme to something like:

```
 myapp://www.myhost.com/static/default.css
```

then `cachedResponseForRequest:` no longer gets called when the html is being loaded.  Does anyone know why this, or how I can enable this method for my url with a specific scheme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to register your own subclass of NSURLProtocol, which can respond to your custom scheme in order to load those special resources.  I used the following two methods:

```
#pragma mark - Public

+ (void)enable {
    [NSURLProtocol registerClass:[MyAppURLProtocol class]];
}

#pragma mark - NSURLProtocol Overridden methods

+ (BOOL)canInitWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request {
    NSString *urlScheme = [[request URL] scheme];
    return [urlScheme isEqualToString:@"myapp"];
}
```

To register, call `[MyAppURLProtocol enable]` from the app delegate.  You also need to override all other required methods defined in the [NSURLProtocol reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLProtocol_Class/Reference/Reference.html), which ultimately forces you to load the data yourself..

The reason why it is necessary to register your own url protocol is [documented by apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Concepts/URLOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001834-155857) as:

> The URL loading system design allows a client application to extend
>   the protocols that are supported for transferring data. The URL
>   loading system natively supports http, https, file, and ftp protocols.
>
> Custom protocols are implemented by subclassing NSURLProtocol and then
>   registering the new class with the URL loading system using the
>   NSURLProtocol class method registerClass:...